# How to record Oracle forms/applications using Jmeter?

Tags: oracle, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to record Oracle forms such as RMS, RPM using Jmeter. I tried recording using HTTP sampler however haven't got any recording.
I believe Jmeter doesn't have inbuilt samplers for recording Oracle applications. Could someone please suggest if Jmeter can record such Oracle forms?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Forms Applets are sending HTTP requests and use the proxy defined in the browser. So, it's possible to record those requests with JMeter or Fiddler.

However, the problem is those request contain binary data which is a dynamically encrypted messaging protocol between the Oracle Forms Applet and the remote server. Replaying the traffic as is won't work because the encryption changes on each replay.

**Only very expensive paid load testing tools** like LoadRunner support Oracle Forms. And even with those tools, it's a pain to load test Oracle Forms applications. It's a GUI based protocol which sends GUI Events to the server.

I've implemented Oracle Forms binary protocol support in NeoLoad (from Neotys) years ago (back in 2007 - 2008), and it took several years to make it work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!